# How to present view controller from background event such as incoming call or timer?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, webrtc, twilio

What is the proper way to present a view controller from an asynchronous event?  I've got an incoming call and would like to pop up a modal view controller.  I've seen this pattern

```
private func presentingVC() -> UIViewController? {
  if let rootViewController = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController {
    var presentedVC = rootViewController
    while true {
      if let nextPresentedVC = presentedVC.presentedViewController {
        presentedVC = nextPresentedVC
      } else {
        return presentedVC
      }
    }
  }
  NSLog("presentingVC did not find root a rootViewController")
  return nil
}
...
presentingVC().presentViewController(callAlert, ...)
```

But it doesn't work reliably.  This pattern finds the top view controller and tries to present over it.  It allows for race conditions, in which the top view controller is dismissed by some other event, at exactly the time that you're trying to present over it.

What is the proper way to present a pop-up, such as to answer / decline an incoming call?

Comment: Could you capture the calculation and presentation in the main loop?